# How to make const apply to C++ class members that are shared pointers

Tags: c++, boost, constants, shared-ptr

I'm struggling a bit trying to work out how to pass const pointers to classes around using shared pointers.  Normally you just declare a pointer to an object `const` and you can no longer change any members in it, however if the class is using shared pointers the `const` does not seem to apply.

Here is a compilable example of the problem.  In `processA()`, it should not be possible to add another element to the vector as the object is supposed to be `const`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct C {
    int value;
};

struct B {
    std::vector<C> vectorOfC;
};

struct A {
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> PtrA;

void processA(boost::shared_ptr<const A> a)
{
    // This should not be possible because 'a' points to const
    C c2;
    c2.value = 456;
    a->b->vectorOfC.push_back(c2);

    for (std::vector<C>::const_iterator
            i = a->b->vectorOfC.begin(); i != a->b->vectorOfC.end(); i++
    ) {
            std::cout << i->value << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    C c;
    c.value = 123;

    PtrA a(new A);
    a->b.reset(new B);
    a->b->vectorOfC.push_back(c);

    processA(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `shared_pointer<const T>` not work?

Comment: Making a const means you can't change b, but says nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how `const` works with pointers.

`const T *` doesn't declare a `const` pointer, it declares a pointer to `const`.  I.e. the pointer is mutable, but the thing(s) it points at are not.

When you add `const` to a pointer, you actually get `T * const`, which is a `const` pointer to mutable object(s), i.e. you can still change the pointee through the pointer.

In the case of `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`) adding `const` leaves you with `const std::shared_ptr<T>`, i.e. you cannot change the `shared_ptr`, but you can change the pointee, because the `shared_ptr` does not point to an immutable object.

To rectify this, you want to use `std::shared_ptr<const T>`, which is a mutable `shared_ptr` to a `const` object.

You can get around this by:

1. Making your `boost::shared_ptr`s pointers to `const`, or, if in certain instances it's acceptable to mutate the pointee
2. Using overloads of a getter (one overload being `const`, the other being mutable) to properly return `boost::shared_ptr<const T>` in the proper case, or, if callers don't actually need the `boost::shared_ptr` itself
3. Using overloads of a getter (one overload being `const`, the other being mutable) to return references to `T`, with the `const` overload returning `const T &` and the mutable overload returning `T &`

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Looks like some refactoring is needed if I want to enforce this behaviour, replacing the members with get/set functions.  Thanks!  I'm marking this as the correct answer because it also includes some ways around the problem.

Answer (score 3):

All this stuff about `shared_ptr` is just a red herring.

You have pointer to a `const` object that has a pointer to a non-`const` object.

You can of course modify the latter object.

Comment: You're right.  For some reason I completely forgot that applying `const` to an object makes the pointers in it immutable, but it doesn't change anything about the objects they point to!  Thanks for the reminder :-)